# Perforce file size different then what is on disc

Tags: perforce

We saw an odd behavior with one user pushing a file to perforce. The original file on disk is `393846` bytes where the file after submitting to perforce became `393382`. So where did the missing 464 bytes go?

Extra Details:

- All parties Windows
- Asset Type: Binary (Unreal Assets)

Comment: Details, please! Information about the operating system, software version file type, how you took these measurements, what possible theories you've already investigated, etc. are all needed. My guess is that you've got a Mac or a Windows client and the difference is due to line end encoding differences. Another possibility would be RCS keyword expansion. But you'd have to provide a lot more information to figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: Hey @BryanPendleton tried to add some more details. Anything else needed?

Comment: Seeing the actual output that you're getting this info from would be good.  I'll add an example to my answer so you can see what that information looks like and possibly add it to your question if you have a case that's not already covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text files are normalized to LF-terminated lines (aka "unix-style") on the server.  On individual clients, the files are rendered in the native format, which means CRLF-terminated lines on Windows.

Hence if a file with 464 lines is submitted from a Windows client, it will have 464 fewer bytes when it's stored on the server because all of the CR bytes will have been removed.  When it's synced back to a Windows client (any Windows client), the CRs will be put back in.  Here's an example of how that'd look:

```
C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 fstat -Ol text.txt
... depotFile //collaborators/main/python/text.txt
... clientFile c:\Perforce\test\python\text.txt
... isMapped
... headAction edit
... headType text
... headTime 1595542603
... headRev 4
... headChange 181
... headModTime 1595542590
... haveRev 4
... fileSize 148
... digest A6A7BF7DF3274FAA12F6BC394DFC2C69


C:\Perforce\test\python>dir text.txt
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is AE05-0B05

 Directory of C:\Perforce\test\python

07/23/2020  03:16 PM               157 text.txt
               1 File(s)            157 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  789,006,692,352 bytes free

C:\Perforce\test\python>wc -l text.txt
9 text.txt
```

Note that `fileSize` as returned by `fstat -Ol` is 148 whereas the local file size returned by `dir` is 157 bytes; the difference of 9 bytes is because the `headType` is `text` (also shown by `fstat -Ol`) and the file is 9 lines long, as shown by `wc -l`.

As Bryan pointed out in the comments, keyword expansion can also account for a difference between what was submitted from the client and what lands on the server, although in that scenario the client file will be refreshed such that *after* the submit has fully completed the client-side and server-side files will have the same keyword content and size (discounting the already-mentioned line ending translation).

If the file has the `unicode` type that could also account for a difference, since Unicode files are normalized to UTF-8 on the server; a UTF-16 file that mostly contains characters that have a single-byte UTF-8 representation will end up quite a bit smaller on the server, for example.

For a file with the `binary` type I would not expect there to be a difference between the size on the client and the (pre-compression) size on the server.

Comment: I guess it now makes sense, I had some time to check the files again, and some of the `.uassets` had as the Perforce filetype `text` is there a way to tell perforce that `.uassets` are always binary?

Comment: You can use `p4 typemap` to configure the server's choice of file types: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v16.1/cmdref/p4_typemap.html